# reading in large data set in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am attempting read a large data file into Fortran it contains about 40960000 rows, I later convert it to a matrix so it would be 6400 * 6400. When I try my code using a much smaller data set it works fine. However, it tells me that there is a segmentation fault, when I use my larger dataset.  I suspect that it is a memory allocation issue. Is there a way to allocate more memory or otherwise correct this problem.

```
   program infectgrid
   implicit none

   integer ::  i,  individual, nedge,&
    tempinfect_tim_err, dumnum_infalpha0, dumnum_infalpha1, alpha0counter, &
    alpha1counter, obsrand,  minvalshift

    character (LEN = 50) :: parameterfilelabel,  parameterfile, networkfilelabel,        infectfilenamelabel, networkfile, infectfilename
             !allocatable to allow for reading in of individuals and time periods
   integer, dimension(:) , allocatable :: xcord, ycord, dummy3, recover_tim1, recover_tim2, &
     recover_tim3, recover_tim4, recover_tim5,  sampleadjshort, shortsamplecount, &
     cov1dum, covlog, covvect1uni

    character, dimension (:), allocatable :: rec
   integer, dimension (:, :) ,  allocatable :: link  
    real, dimension(:) , allocatable  :: alphavect

    call random_seed

 open(12, file = "filenamesinfection.txt", status = "old")

 read(12, *) parameterfile, networkfile, infectfilename
 close(12)

 open(12, file = parameterfile, status = "old")
 read(12, *)  individualname, alpha0name, alpha1name
 read(12, *) individual, alpha0, alpha1

  nedge = individual*individual

allocate(rec(1:nedge))
allocate(xcord(1:nedge))
allocate(ycord(1:nedge))
allocate(dummy3(1:nedge))
allocate(sampleadjshort(1:nedge))
allocate(shortsamplecount(1:nedge))
allocate(covlog(1:nedge))
allocate(cov1dum(1:nedge))


allocate(link(1:individual, 1:individual))


   link = 0
   covlog = 0

    print *, individual, alpha0, alpha1
    print *, link(individual, individual)

    print *, "test"
   open(10, file = networkfile, status = "old")
   print *, networkfile       
   print *, "test"
   do i = 1, nedge

   read ( 10, *) rec(i),  xcord(i), ycord(i), dummy3(i), cov1dum(i), sampleadjshort(i),      shortsamplecount(i)    

   if (dummy3(i) == 1)  then 

   link(xcord(i), ycord(i)) = 1
    end if

    if (xcord(i) == ycord(i)) then 
    covlog(i) = 1
    end if
    end do
    close(10)

    covvect1uni = pack(cov1dum, covlog == 1)

    print *, "xcord",  xcord(nedge), "ycord",  ycord(nedge)
    print *, link(individual, individual)
    print *, "test"
```

The file prints out the first and second "test" but does not print out the link statement nor the line starting with "xcord" and soon after gives me a segmentation fault  i.e. Segmentation fault     nohup ./swnetworkinfectrecoveralpha05covgeo2.out

as to compiler options, I think that I am using most of what is available:  ifort -free  -O2 -stand f03 -check bounds -traceback -warn all -fstack-protector -assume protect_parens -implicitnone  -o swnetworkinfectrecoveralpha05covgeo2.out swnetworkinfectrecoveralpha05covgeo2.f90

Comment: Please show the declarations of the variables in the read statement's io-list.  Also, what is/are your compiler, platform and compile options.

Comment: @IanH, have made necessary changes as per your request.

Comment: Have you calculated how much memory your `allocate` statements attempt to grab and compare that with the available RAM on your system ?  By my reckoning your program needs about `(8*individual^2 + individual^4)*b` bytes, where `b` is the size (in bytes) of a default character (or numeric) storage unit. I haven't distinguished between the two types in your code but you probably ought to.

Comment: My guess is that if nedge is large then the assignment with the pack intrinsic call causes something akin to the name of this site because of compiler temporaries.  Try the -heap-arrays option and read [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/determining-root-cause-of-sigsegv-or-sigbus-errors)

Comment: @IanH: I encourage you to post an answer. Jourdan: I encourage you to accept said answer if Ian's solution solved your problem.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for better visibility. Fortran 90 is just one specific (and old) version.